# PHP: scope of session variables - cookies disabled

Tags: php

Am I right assuming that session variables are available on the same page even if cookies are turned off?

I need a global array in my script (not across pages, only in the current script). When registering on top of the script:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array('ok');
```

then $_SESSION['test'] will be 'ok' in every included file, function and class, even if cookies are disbled?

Thanks for advise.

Comment: Have you tried the following
$test = array('ok');
function myFunc() {
    global $test;
    // do stuff with test
}

Comment: So you hate globals but you want to use them? That does not make sense....

Comment: @Felix: I know. But using $GLOBALS seems to look better to me, even if its the same : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a global variable use [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). Of course even better would be to restructure your code and pass the required values as parameters.

But yes, sessions are also possible without cookies. Then the session ID is not stored in a cookie, but passed in the URL. But why "abuse" sessions?

[More information about variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Btw, I think you mean $GLOBALS : )

Comment: @Ilyssis: Ups. Yes :) Fixed (got confused from `$_GET` and `$_POST`...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if cookie is disable.
You can call your session whatever scope you are in your program, if you want to unset the session, then you need to use

```
unset($_SESSION['test']);
```

Another day, I had delete all my cookies, and the variable session was ON in my pages.. until I unset it...

unset can be used to GLOBALS and all variables you wish to destroy.

To destroy all data registered to a session, then use `session_destroy`
 in this case the session variable still exists but empty.

That's All!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on what sessions are. Session in php can be used on any page as long as session_start() is your first line of code. Any session variables set then  will be accessible on any page until the user ends there session, usually by closing there browser. Disabling cookies will not hinder your use of sessions.

Comment: The session id will be stored in a cookie though, and there is a php setting that will prevent you from passing the session ID through GET. So in some cases, disabling cookies will hinder the use of sessions.

Comment: session_start() doesn't have to be the first line of code. It simply has to be called before any output is generated. And disabling cookies does hinder session - you can pass the session ID through hidden form fields and on the URL, but there's plenty of places that PHP will not/cannot automatically add the token, which means much more work for you.

Comment: Thanks for both your comments. I'll try to remember them for the future.